# How to add username and password to electron desktop app on installation?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to add username and password to a desktop app made in electron and react.
but I want to add them only on installing the app like authentication.
this app doesn't connect to external server so i need some basic security for it.

i saw this in some other apps on install they ask to add username and password and then when you try to open the app. the app asks you to enter the pre-saved username and password.

How i can do something like this in electron with react.